# Export report to XML (Access)

Tags: ms-access, vba

i'm using Access 2010.
I want to export a report to XML.(using vba)
I'm using:             DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "rptName"
and it works..but it ask from the user to choose format and place.
I want that it will automaticlly ..

how can i do it?

thanks!!

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [Application.ExportXML Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193212%28v=office.14%29.aspx) to export the report's data like this:

```
ExportXML acExportReport, "rptName", "C:\SomeFolder\rptName.xml"
```

If you want more than just the report's data, `ExportXML` also supports an option to include presentation information.  I've never tried that, though.

Answer (score 1):

**DoCmd.OutputTo Method**

The OutputTo method carries out the OutputTo action in Visual Basic.
Syntax:

> .OutputTo(ObjectType, ObjectName, OutputFormat, OutputFile, AutoStart, TemplateFile, Encoding, OutputQuality)

**OutputFormat** is the format required:

- acFormatASP
- acFormatHTML
- acFormatIIS
- acFormatPDF
- acFormatRTF
- acFormatSNP
- acFormatTXT
- acFormatXLS
- acFormatXPS

**OutputFile** is the filename to save the item to

Comment: ok, I see that even `DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputTable, "MyTable", "XML (*.xml)", "C:\temp\test.xml"` still gives a prompt on the information that needs to be exported (data/schema/presentation)

Comment: `acFormat???` is a string, which corresponds to the list given in the dialog box that appears when you don't supply an output format value (that's why **"XML (*xml)"** works in my test to send out XML)